# How can I split an 2d array of chars, into smaller arrays in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an 2d array of chars and i want to split it into smaller arrays. The 2d array is 4*4, and i want to split this 2d array into 4 different arrays. All arrays have four elements.

```
- For example I have this 2d array:
     1 2 5 6
     3 4 7 8
     4 4 4 7
     4 4 5 1
- And i want cut it for this arrays:
  [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8] [4,4,4,4] [4,7,5,1]
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] and study [ask] very soon.

Comment: please provide at least some code which shows how you tried to solve this problem. Furthermore, please don't post pictures of text, and at least try to explain the rules according to which you want to split your matrix. Usually when you do this, you actually start describing in your own word the algorithm to solve your problem

Comment: The question is a valid question, but in order to get good answers it is prefered to follows the rules of good posts. Please [edit] the question and replace the image with code blocks. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more information.

Comment: Is it _always_ 4*4 and you _always_ want the four "quadrants"? Or what would the expected outputs for differently sized inputs look like?

Comment: @xdtTransform - It looks like OP is asking for "quadrants" (or "sub matrices"), not rows/columns.

Comment: @Corak The 2d array is not always 4*4. But the arrays always have four elements. The 2d array is just two power(4,8,16,32,64,128). And the row and column lenght is same in the 2d array

Answer (score 2):

The naive way is to loop through the elements.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var matrix = new int[,] { 
            { 1, 2, 5, 6 },
            { 3, 4, 7, 8 },
            { 4, 4, 4, 7 },
            { 4, 4, 5, 1 }
        };

        var array11 = matrix.GetSubMatrixElements(0, 0, 2, 2);
        // [1, 2, 3, 4]
        var array12 = matrix.GetSubMatrixElements(0, 2, 2, 2);
        // [5, 6, 7, 8]
        var array21 = matrix.GetSubMatrixElements(2, 0, 2, 2);
        // [4, 4, 4, 4]
        var array22 = matrix.GetSubMatrixElements(2, 2, 2, 2);
        // [4, 7, 5, 1]
    }

    public static T[] GetSubMatrixElements<T>(this T[,] matrix, int startRow, int startCol, int rowCount, int colCount)
    {
        var array = new T[rowCount*colCount];

        int index = 0;
        for (int i = startRow; i < startRow+rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = startCol; j < startCol+colCount; j++)
            {
                array[index++] = matrix[i, j];
            }
        }

        return array;
    }
```

---

If you want faster results for, you can use `Buffer.BlockCopy()` in place of the inner loop.

```
    public static T[] GetSubMatrixElements<T>(this T[,] matrix, int startRow, int startCol, int rowCount, int colCount)
    {
        int n = matrix.GetLength(0), m = matrix.GetLength(1);
        var array = new T[rowCount*colCount];
        int u = Buffer.ByteLength(matrix)/(n*m);
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = startRow; i < startRow+rowCount; i++)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(matrix, u*(i*m+startCol), array, u*index, u*colCount);
            index += colCount;
        }
        return array;
    }
```